# Passing IntPtr through COM interop

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop

How can I invoke an interface method that requires an `IntPtr` parameter?  This is working just fine if my method requires a `string`, but not if it requires `IntPtr`.  Here's an example interface in C#:

```
[
    Guid("etc-etc-etc"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch),
    ComVisible(true)
]
public interface ICallback
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void CallbackWithString( string value );

    [DispId(2)]
    void CallbackWithHandle( IntPtr value );
}
```

I derive a COM class in C# from this interface, and pass its dispatch into my C++ application (via COM).  Later on, that C++ application invokes my methods on that dispatch to provide notifications back to the C# application.

**This works:**

```
CComPtr<IDispatch> obj;      // My C# COM interop object, stored in my C++ app
VARIANT arg;

arg.vt = VT_BSTR;
arg.bstrVal = myString;
obj.InvokeN( L"CallbackWithString", &arg, 1 );
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
arg.vt = VT_HANDLE;          // I also tried VT_BYREF, VT_VOID|VT_BYREF, and VT_INT_PTR
arg.byref = myHandle;
obj.InvokeN( L"CallbackWithHandle", &arg, 1 );
```

By "doesn't work", I mean that the function is not called, but no exception is raised.

Is it possible to send an `IntPtr` through COM interop?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not VT_HANDLE, that's a hack from OleCtl.h.  The SSCLI20 version of the CLR has its variant marshaling code in clr/src/vm/olevariant.cpp.  It converts a VT_INT to IntPtr.  That's however a 32-bit type, I think you'll need VT_I8 if this needs to work in 64-bit code.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  It still doesn't work if my parameter is declared as `IntPtr`.  I had to change it to an integer.  I went with `UInt64`, even though I'm only using 32-bit code.  I had preferred not to do this, and use `IntPtr`, but that seems to be a recipe for frustration.